# How to save 2 data on one redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to store 2 key-value data for 2 different programs . These data may have the same key but different value. If I don't separate them these will crash my program. So how can I store both data on 1 redis and how to configure it using nodeJS.

Comment: Although best practice is to use multiple instances, Redis also has a [database number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13386053/2395796) that can be used for namespacing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does redis separates the multiple user instance running on same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161719/how-does-redis-separates-the-multiple-user-instance-running-on-same-server)